Adjusting the Horizontal Space Between the Text and the Footnote Mark
MWE:
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in,paperwidth=3.5in,paperheight=2.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[para]{footmisc}
\usepackage[tracking=true]{microtype}
\usepackage{baskervald}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\large
\setcounter{footnote}{16} 
``This is a sentence.''\footnote{And a footnote.}
\end{document}

which gives

How may I increase the horizontal spacing between the text (in this case, between the closing pair of quotes and the footnote mark "17")? I would like to do this globally; that is, for all the footnotes in a document.

A rude solution: insert \, before \footnote{And a footnote.}

@Zarko Yes, and so would also leaving a space between the quotes and the \footnote command increase the spacing as well---but that would be too much. I am hoping to be able to define a very small amount.

@cfr What do you mean by \kern0.1pt? I am looking for a global solution to act accordingly on many footnotes. Adjusting the horizontal spacing for one footnote alone is easy enough. I would like to know how to do this for many footnotes at once.

@Jethro you need to set up a font for greek. if you use the default computer modern, there's a version for greek available. if you use a font like baskervald, which doesn't support greek, you need to tell latex which font you'd like it to use for greek. otherwise, it falls back to computer modern but doesn't do so in an entirely successful way. this is nothing to do with baskervald. you'd get the same effect if you loaded any font package which changed the font to something which doesn't support greek. see the babel package for examples of how to do this/look in the online font catalogue.

[Edited: different implementation.]
As I said in the comment you dismissed, you can use \kern to add a small space. One way to do this is to use a generic kernel hook to insert the space just before \footnote. Since \footnote is not used when printing the footnotes, this will not affect the spacing there. However, it will still add space in other contexts e.g. if a different character precedes the footnote marker. It will also not affect cases where the footnote marker is typeset separately from the footnote text, since \footnote is not used in these cases.

Note that you need not load fontenc just for T1 if using baskervald as the package enables T1 already. The fonts are only available in T1, so, if you are loading the package, the code assumes you want to enable the encoding necessary to use the fonts1.
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in,paperwidth=3.5in,paperheight=2.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage[para]{footmisc}
\usepackage[tracking=true]{microtype}
\usepackage{baskervald}
\AddToHook {cmd/footnote/before}{\kern 0.5pt}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\large
``This is a sentence.''\footnote{And a footnote.}

\setcounter{footnote}{16}

``This is a sentence.''\footnote{And a footnote.}
\end{document}

1Note that this is not true for berenis. If you load berenis you must explicitly request T1 as the default is LY1.

Thank you for your helpful answer; however, I have noticed that if I increase the kerning from 0.5pt to something higher, the listing of the footnotes below the footnote line get shifted to the right accordingly. Would you know of a way how to prevent this?

@Jethro to followup my earlier comment, see edit above. this adds the space in a completely different way. It does not affect the spacing when the footnotes are printed, because it is used only when \footnote itself is expanded. there are probably some disadvantages with any reasonably feasible approach, but I think this is cleaner than the method I suggested before and should give better results. in particular, I don't think it will make anything worse, as my original did. however, if \footnote isn't used, this version won't insert the space, whereas the original would have.

Thank you for your revised answer; although I had hoped that there would be a solution that does not use AddToHook---as my favorite "old" computer does not have the capability of invoking it :-) --- it nevertheless works fine on my newer computer with a reasonably up-to-date version of TeXLive.

@Jethro you could always use \apptocmd from etoolbox. (just don't tell egreg I suggested this :-).)  for that matter, you might be able to get away with something like \let\origfootnote\footnote \renewcommand\footnote{\kern 0.5pt\origfootnote} but I've not tested this.

The latter seems to work fine on my end. Many thanks.
